# How to match value with comma separated string using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help. I need to match some value with one variable containing value which is comma separated string using Angular.js or Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
var special="2,1,4,5";
```

Here I need to search lets say `1` is present in this comma separated string or not. If the given value is present it will return true otherwise false.Please help.

Answer (score 3):

With array split

```
var found = special.split(",").indexOf("1") > -1;
```

---

```js
var special="2,1,4,5";
var found = special.split(",").indexOf("1") > -1;
console.log(found); // true
```

---

Just to prove that String's indexOf won't work

```js
var special="2,11,4,5";
var found = special.indexOf("1") > -1;
console.log(found); // true but actual should be false as there is no 1
```

Comment: why to split when you can directly use `indexOf` on string

Comment: @AmberNemani Big NOOO.  If you search for `1` and the element is `11`, String's `indexOf` returns true. Added a demo for the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var special="2,1,4,5";
var searchFor="1";
var index=special.split(",").indexOf(searchFor);
if(index === -1) return false;
else return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the string to an array like this:

```
var specialArray = special.split(',');
```

Once you have an array you can use `indexOf` to find the item in the array.

```
var itemIndex = specialArray.indexOf('1');
```

`itemIndex` will be `-1` when the value you're looking for isn't in the array. When the result of `indexOf` is greater than `-1` it is the index of the item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this:

```
/(^|,)1(,|$)/.test("2,1,4,5") // => true
```

just to test negative case

```
/(^|,)1(,|$)/.test("2,11,4,5") // => false
```

If you have multiline string (that contains `\r\n`), use `/(^|,)1(,|$)/m` instead